# Write the memory of my own process without using WriteProcessMemory

Tags: delphi

I have 2 global vars

```
Value1, Value2 : Cardinal;
```

To get the values I use the following function.

```
procedure GetValues;
var
  Modulo : HMODULE;
  GetWindowTextAAPI: PDWord;
begin
  Modulo := GetModuleHandle('user32.dll');
  if (Modulo <> 0) then
  begin
    GetWindowTextAAPI := GetProcAddress(Modulo, 'GetWindowTextA');
    if (GetWindowTextAAPI <> nil) then
    begin
      Value1 := GetWindowTextAAPI^;
      Value2 := GetWindowTextAAPI^+4;
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(Value1)+' '+IntToStr(Value2));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

To write I use

```
procedure WriteValues;
var
  Modulo : HMODULE;
  Write : Cardinal;
  GetWindowTextAAPI: PDWord;
begin
  Modulo := GetModuleHandle('user32.dll');
  if (Modulo <> 0) then
  begin
    GetWindowTextAAPI := GetProcAddress(Modulo, 'GetWindowTextA');
    if (GetWindowTextAAPI <> nil) then
    begin
      WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, Pointer(GetWindowTextAAPI), Addr(Value1), SizeOf(Value1), Write);
      WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, Pointer(DWORD(GetWindowTextAAPI)+4), Addr(Value2),SizeOf(Value2), Write);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

How use `Move` to simplify?
I really need to use WriteProcessMemory to write in memory of my own process?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?  The `Windows` unit provides the `GetWindowText` function, and if you were trying to import it yourself this just seems mind bogglingly roundabout...

Comment: I think what OP wants to do is to modify the code of one of his functions at runtime. Right?

Comment: Think about it, to assign a value to one of your variables do you call WriteProcessMemory?

Comment: There is another process that makes a Win API Hook in my process, I capture the original value when my form start and write it when the function is hooked,  I'm taking the starting address of GetWindowTextA and writing if the value has been changed by Hook.

Comment: You need to change the protection with VirtualProtect

Comment: By the time you do all of that you might conclude that WriteProcessMemory is a perfectly reasonable way to do this. Certainly it will be more concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alternative to write bytes in memory

```
function WriteBytes(pAddress: Pointer; Bytes: Array of Byte): Boolean;
var
  OldProtect , NewProtect : DWORD;
begin
  if VirtualProtect(pAddress, SizeOf(Bytes), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @OldProtect) then
  begin
    Move(Bytes, pAddress^, Length(Bytes));
    VirtualProtect(pAddress, SizeOf(Bytes), OldProtect, @NewProtect);
    Result := True;
  end
  else
  Result := False;
end;
```

use

```
const
  OriginalValue : Array[0..5] of byte = ($6A,$08,$68,$F0,$FB,$DF);
var
  Modulo : HMODULE;
  GetWindowTextAAPI: PDWord;
begin
  Modulo := GetModuleHandle('user32.dll');
  if (Modulo <> 0) then
  begin
    GetWindowTextAAPI := GetProcAddress(Modulo, 'GetWindowTextA');
    if (GetWindowTextAAPI <> nil) then
    begin
      WriteBytes(GetWindowTextAAPI,OriginalValue);
    end;
  end;
end;
```